# Source for custom rackmount chassis to build bulk storage server?

Tags: hardware, rackmount

I need to build a couple of really large bulk storage servers for a project I am working on. I don't need fast response, just big, dumb storage. lots of it to hold statistical data going back to the turn of the last century. I was thinking to build something like the [Backblaze od](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/). I have all the parts except the chassis to hold the drives in the vertical configuration. I am having a hard time sourcing this part.

Anyone know a supplier that can build these things, one off or maybe even is producing them in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

Backblack supplier: http://www.protocase.com/

You may looke at the DDN version of the sun x4540/sata beast. I'm not sure of the price, but it may be another avenue.

As you investigate the backblaze type pod, you might see the critiques from Joerg Shilling in two blog posts. Nice reads, which might help in your architecture process.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Nexsan makes the SATAbeast, which is basically exactly like the Backblaze.

http://www.nexsan.com/satabeast.php

I've had good experiences with them in the past and it's what the Argonne National Laboratory uses to store their software mirror.

Comment: Interesting, but I think those are beyond my budget. I think a sata beast is around 40k and I am trying to get into something for around 10k.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm advertising for them =D But I do believe the 40k price is a for one fully populated with 1TB drives. Of course I have no idea what just the chassis would cost =/

Comment: I really appreciate the help. with a the backblaze I can get 67tb for around 10k. I dont need the speed so much as I need ability to store the data so this is why I am heading down this path.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK there is:
http://www.openstoragesystems.co.uk/products/backblaze-storage-pod which sell the Backblaze enclosure for GBP 570.

A local sheet metal fabrication company should be able to produce them from the CAD drawing. [C&T Custom Fabrication](http://ctcustomfab.com/) has been producing Backblaze pod cases for http://www.colostate.edu/~curtisb/mass_storage/